# click a button and select a drop down item in a webpage

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I call up the following webpage in an iframe that I do not have scripting access:
https://docmein.com/app/page/12801944916418372

I enclose the above page in the page:
https://www.barnwellmd.com/patients/docmeinframe.html.

When I open the docmein.com page, I would like to automatically click the button:

SCHEDULE NOW

Then when the "Request New Appointment" popup opens (click on "Schedule Now" to see it) I would like to automatically select "1ST appointment for NEW PATIENTS" in the service drop down box.

Is this possible? If so, how?

TIA

Comment: No, this is not possible, as you said you don't have access to it. So i'm guessing it also not the same domain. So won't work due to security restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Use html selected attribute in option tag of input type=select

Your output looks likes

```
<select class="GNAI25MLJ" aria-hidden="false">
<option value="15257" selected="selected">1ST appointment for NEW PATIENTS (2 hours)</option>
<option value="15256">EXISTING patient followup visit ONLY (1 hour)</option></select>
```